# Internal Links Between InDesign Documents Don't Work

Tags: epub, html, editing, indesign

First, a little background: I created a series of documents, each one representing a chapter in my book. Then I created a book and imported all the documents into it. It seems to be working OK; when I export it as an epub, I can page through all the chapters.

But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make internal hyperlinks. Actually, I created a hyperlink on the first page of chapter (document) 1, pointing it to a text anchor on the last page of the document. It works.

But when I move the text anchor to a different document, it doesn't work.

The link on page 1 looks like this:

```
<a href="#_idTextAnchor001" id="A1" title="Link">LINK</a>
```

(I inserted an ID, so I can link back to it from my end notes.)

And this is what the text anchor looks like:

I am a TEXT ANCHOR.

I created it with InDesign's Hyperlinks Panel, though I'm doing a lot of work with BBEdit, modifying files in a published epub.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is or how I can troubleshoot it?

**EDIT:**

I've learned that, when linking between separate HTML files, you have to include the name of the file. So a link in Chapter1.html pointing to Chapter2.html should look something like this:

```
<a href="Chapter2.html#101" title="Reference">101</a>
```

However, my links from Chapter2 back to Chapter1 don't work for some reason. It's probably just some little semantic bug I have to figure out.

Comment: Should I delete this question? The problem was simply incorrect anchors; I was writing id="#1" instead of id="1".

Comment: You might as well answer it yourself. That's allowed. You could expand on it by saying how to handle relative links to files in a folder.